# Can't pass argv to function

Tags: c

Here is my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void help(const char *argv);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    const char *p;
    int x;

    for(x = 0; x < argc; x++) {
        p = argv[x];
        if(*p == '-') {
            p++;
        }
        switch(*p) {    
            case 'h':
                help(*argv);
                return 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void help(const char *argv) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s: [option]\n", argv[0]);
}
```

The problem is that during compile process I get

> warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type
>   ‘int’

How to print program name in help function ?

Comment: Declare the argument as `char *argv []`, not `char *argv`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That should be

```
help(argv);
```

and

```
void help(const char **argv) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s: [option]\n", argv[0]);
}
```

Using a `char**` because you are passing an array of strings (aka pointers to char).

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to dereference it. `[0]` is the same as `*argv`, which would be a `char`, when you want a `char*`.

```
void help(const char *argv) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s: [option]\n", argv);
}
```

Alternatively, you may want to do it this way:

```
help(argv); // don't dereference

//...

void help(const char **argv) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s: [option]\n", argv[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

start by changing

```
void help(const char *argv);
```

to

```
void help(const char *argv[]);
//or
void help(const char **argv);
```

next change

```
void help(const char *argv) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s: [option]\n", argv[0]);
}
```

to
v

```
oid help(const char **argv) { // or with []...
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s: [option]\n", argv[0]);
}
```

and call it like:

```
help(argv);
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you pass a variable in C, make sure you don't change the type of the variable, with the one exception that you can convert an array representation to a pointer representation.  So

```
char *argv[]
```

should be received as

```
char **argv
```

and then the passing is simply

```
myfunc(argv);
```